# FPDM outputs corrupted PDF, and I am not sure why

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am a beginner in PHP programming, and am trying to create a web interface that allows users to maintain an expense database that they can use to file their taxes at the end of the year. Basically, the web interface has a button that, when clicked, is supposed to fill and output a filled-out IRS 1040 form. For this purpose, I am using FDPF and FPDM. However, FPDF seems to output corrupted PDFs. Here is the problematic code:

```
ob_start();
require('./fpdf.php');
require('./fpdm.php');
$pdf = new FPDM('1040_Form_Template.pdf');
$fields = array(
       //This array is very long and fairly simple - I won't ask you to read it all!
       //It contains the values I wish to enter for each field in the 1040 form. 
);
$pdf->useCheckboxParser = true;
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output('I', 'sample_output.pdf');
ob_end_flush();
set_time_limit(0);
```

When I click the button on the web interface that runs this code, I get the following output;
[Chrome PDF error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bK6ny.jpg)

This makes me think that, for some reason, fpdf/fpdm are producing corrupt PDFs. I have tried several different viewers and none of them can open the files that my interface produces.

I would greatly appreciate any insight that you have to offer. Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you save the PDF to a file instead of sending it to the browser? I would also try removing the `ob_start();` and `ob_end_flush();` as they shouldn't really be needed.

Comment: Hi Dave- when I save the PDF to a file instead of sending it to the browser, I'm unable to open that file with any pdf viewer (they all give me some variant of "Unable to open file", depending on the viewer). Removing ob_start() and ob_end_flush() results in the error "FPDF-Merge Error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file"